# Google chrome pc v42, 43 generates gibberish on some fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face, font-family

On a site I'm working on for a client I have a problem i never have come across before.

When visiting a direct link to a sub page on Google Chrome pc v 42 or 43 (not sure about earlier) som of the Proxima Nova font-weight 900 becomes gibberish.

If i change browser size or inspect it all falls back into place. If i navigate from example front page it works as expected. Don't get it on Mac or any other browser so far.

If i remove the font totally it is still there when falling back to Helvetica. Think it might med character encoding but not sure why it would resolve on browser resize then.

http://www.lindau.se/kategorier/forelasaretalare

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Thats not gibberish, its swedish!

Comment: Im of course not talking about the Swedish words but the lack of Swedish in some of the words as they are shown as  random characters . And sometimes the title also get misplaced to the left instead of centered.